# "A kind of" vs "A"

Tags: word-usage

Here are two sentences that I mix up.

> 1. He is **a kind of person** who gets up early in the morning.
> 2. He is **a person** who gets up early in the morning.

I think the two sentences are the exact same because they refer to one of a group of of people who gets up early in the morning, not a definite one but specific one.
Am I right to think this way?

Comment: The idiomatic way of saying 1 is "He is **the** kind of person": you are identifying him as belonging to a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence has a chance of meaning a person who "gets up early in the morning" for a reason other than it's the type/kind of person he is - i.e. the person has to for his job, but the person may not *want* to.  The first sentence always implies the person would get up early in the morning without anything making him do that.

Though in most usage the distinction probably doesn't matter.